# Getting Iframes on mozilla

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, mozilla

I'm using JavaScript on Mozilla (version 4). Once I get a DOM object and identify the tag as an IFRAME I'd like to get the content and the borders (x,y pixels)of the IFRAME, (if I understand correctly the Iframe is an additional HTML page inside another HTML).

Comment: What do you mean by "content and borders" exactly? Can you clarify? Can you use a framework like jQuery, or do you want to work with pure JS only?

Comment: I prefer not to, however if it'll make my life much easier, I _might_ consider.
I'd like to get the page, just like here:
 var browser = document.getElementById('content').selectedBrowser;
 var page = browser.contentDocument;

Answer (score 0):

Look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLIFrameElement

`contentDocument` and `frameborder` are probably what you are looking for.

Comment: How can I identify a DOM object as an HTMLIFrameElement?